# HTML5 Video Android VideoView

Tags: android, html, video, android-videoview

I am trying to play a video that is passed from a WebView in a VideoView. It works, except VideoView does not want to read it. I keep getting the error:

"Sorry, this video cannot be played."

Here is the code for the VideoView:

```
public class VideoHandler extends Activity {

WebView myWebView;
VideoView myVideoView;
WebChromeClient chromeClient;
WebViewClient wvClient;
Intent in;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.video_player);

   myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
   MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
   mediaController.setAnchorView(myVideoView);
   String video = (MNWVMainPage.myWebView.getUrl());
   myVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
   myVideoView.setVideoPath(video);
   myVideoView.start();


   myVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {         
   @Override  
   public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {  
       mp.stop();  
       mp.release();
       setContentView(R.layout.mnwv_main);  
   }  
  });         
 }  
}
```

Why wont this load the video?

Comment: some of the you tube video also showing this kind of alert, please check whether the video is playable or check whether it is playing in default browser.

Answer (score 0):

From just reading from your code, I can see no error. 
Can you check a few things:

1. Does the video align to the format list [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#recommendations)?
2. Have you open the camera/ another VideoView? Even if you release them, the buffer seems to need some time to be actually released.